# Add .jars in alternative folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse and Java, and I know that `.jar` files I need to add into `libs` derectory so that compiler could recognize them. How I can add `.jar`s not only in `libs` folder but also in other folder too. How can I configure Eclipse to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest if you have the jar files visible in the package explorer to start with, i.e. within your project directory. At that point, you can just right-click on the jar file, go to the "Build path" section of the context menu, then select "Add to build path".

If the jar file is elsewhere and you don't want to move it, you can right-click on the project, and under the "Build path" part of the context menu, select "Add external archives...". Then find the jar file in the file browser, and hit OK.

All of this can also be done from the project properties dialog, in the Java Build Path section.

Answer (score 0):

- Right Click project
- Select Properties
- Select Java Build Path

  - Under Tab Libraries Click on add jars or add external jar to add the required jars

Answer (score 0):

The Java build path is used while compiling a Java project to discover dependent classes . It is made up of the following items:

1. Code in the source folders
2. Jars and classes folder associated with the project
3. Classes and libraries exported by projects referenced by this
   project

Our goal is to feed our classes with the dependent classes present in the jars during compile time. Eclipse provies with number of easy ways to do it .Here you can find a good article about how to add the jars in the projects with screenshorts attached to it http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)